Is the product of exponentiated elliptic curve basis elements invariant under FFT of scalars?
I am working with an elliptic curve defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ and have a basis set of points ${g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_n}$. When I perform the FFT on these points, I obtain a new basis ${h_0, h_1, \ldots, h_n}$.
Additionally, I have a set of scalar field elements ${a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n}$ whose FFT gives me ${v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_n}$. Here, both $a_i$ and $v_i$ are elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$.
I am trying to understand the relationship between these two bases when the scalars are exponentiated. Specifically, I want to know if the following equality holds:
$g_0^{v_0} \cdot g_1^{v_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot g_n^{v_n} = h_0^{a_0} \cdot h_1^{a_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot h_n^{a_n}$
In other words, can I say that the product of the elliptic curve points raised to the powers of the FFT-transformed scalars $v_i$ is equal to the product of the FFT-transformed elliptic curve points $h_i$ raised to the powers of the original scalars $a_i$?
To provide more context:
The elliptic curve is defined over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.
The elements $a_i$ and $v_i$ are assumed to be in the multiplicative group of the field.
Any insights into this relationship or any pointers to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.
